# Python Multiprocessing pool starmap slower than sequential (nontrivial independent function)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using Python 3.6 on an i7 with 8 cores to naively solve a differential equation on a grid. The function (shown below) does a bunch of vectorized computations with numpy (sums, multiplications and dot products) and runs through a for loop updating values at each time step using a running sum.

```
def dynamics(cParams, gParams, sParams):
# takes parameters, performs dynamics, and outputs desired observables
[P, aIBi] = cParams
[kcutoff, dk, Ntheta, dtheta, tMax, dt] = gParams
[mI, mB, n0, gBB] = sParams

kVec = np.arange(dk, kcutoff, dk)
thetaVec = np.arange(dtheta, np.pi, dtheta)
tVec = np.arange(0, tMax, dt)

# initial conditions
Bk0_mat = np.zeros((thetaVec.size, kVec.size), dtype=complex)
Bk0_V = Bk0_mat.reshape(thetaVec.size * kVec.size)
phi0 = 0 + 0j

# precomputing things that only depend on k,theta and not t
Omega0K = omega0_k(kVec, gBB, mI, mB, n0)
Wkv = Wk(kVec, gBB, mB, n0)
gnum = g(aIBi, kcutoff, gBB, mI, mB, n0)
thetaones = np.ones(thetaVec.size)

Omega0K_mat = np.outer(thetaones, Omega0K)
Wk_mat = np.outer(thetaones, Wkv)
dV_mat = (2 * np.pi / (2 * np.pi)**3) * np.outer(dtheta * np.sin(thetaVec), dk * kVec**2)
kcos_mat = np.outer(np.cos(thetaVec), kVec)

Omega0K_Vec = Omega0K_mat.reshape(thetaVec.size * kVec.size)
Wk_Vec = Wk_mat.reshape(thetaVec.size * kVec.size)
Wki_Vec = 1 / Wk_Vec
dV_Vec = dV_mat.reshape(thetaVec.size * kVec.size)
kcos_Vec = kcos_mat.reshape(thetaVec.size * kVec.size)

# calculate differential equation

# setting initial beta vector and initializing matrices
Bkt = Bk0_V
phit = phi0

PB_Vec = np.zeros(tVec.size, dtype=float)
phi_Vec = np.zeros(tVec.size, dtype=complex)
NB_Vec = np.zeros(tVec.size, dtype=float)

for ind, t in enumerate(tVec):
    # keep track of quantities we care about (storing data)

    PBt = PB(Bkt, kcos_Vec, dV_Vec, gBB, mB, n0)
    PB_Vec[ind] = PBt
    # print(PBt)
    phi_Vec[ind] = phit

    NBt = np.dot(Bkt * np.conjugate(Bkt), dV_Vec)
    NB_Vec[ind] = NBt
    # print(NBt)

    # calculate some useful quantities that will be useful later in the loop

    xpt = pchi(Bkt, Wk_Vec, dV_Vec, gBB, mB, n0)
    xmt = mchi(Bkt, Wki_Vec, dV_Vec, gBB, mB, n0)

    # update Bkt and ast to the t+1 value

    BDiff = -1j * (gnum * np.sqrt(n0) * Wk_Vec + Bkt * (Omega0K_Vec - kcos_Vec * (P - PB_Vec[ind]) / mI) + gnum * (Wk_Vec * xpt + Wki_Vec * xmt))
    phiDiff = gnum * n0 + gnum * np.sqrt(n0) * xpt + (P**2 - PB_Vec[ind]**2) / (2 * mI)
    Bkt = Bkt + dt * BDiff
    phit = phit + dt * phiDiff

    # print([PBt, xpt, xmt])

S_Vec = dynOverlap(NB_Vec, phi_Vec)
freqVec, A_Vec = spectFunc(S_Vec, tVec)

# save data
tfData = [tVec, freqVec]
paramData = [cParams, gParams, sParams]
obData = [PB_Vec, NB_Vec, S_Vec, A_Vec]
data = [paramData, tfData, obData]

# return data
# dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# np.save(dirpath + '/pdata/fmquench_aIBi:%.2f_P:%.2f.npy' % (aIBi, P), data)
return data
```

When I try running the function multiple times while changing the input parameters using pool.starmap vs serially (using either a for loop or itertools.starmap), the serial computation is significantly faster. In the example below, I call the function 7 times which takes about 85 seconds per serial run for the defined grid parameters (not shown), totaling to ~512 seconds. When I use a pool using all 8 processors, the runtime is ~705 seconds. The different function calls are not communicating as far as I can tell and the work done by each function call is nontrivial so I don't understand why multiprocessing is slower. What am I doing wrong/where could the bottleneck be in the code that's causing high IPC overhead/whatever is making multiprocessing slower?

```
# create iterable over all tuples of function arguments for dynamics()

paramsIter = zip(cParams_List, it.repeat(gParams), it.repeat(sParams))

# compute data (parallel)

start = timer()

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    # pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.starmap(dynamics, paramsIter)
    # pool.close()
    # pool.join()

end = timer()
print(end - start)

# compute data (serial) - for loop

# start = timer()

# for z in paramsIter:
#     dynamics(*z)

# end = timer()
# print(end-start)

# compute data (serial) - starmap

# start = timer()

# for i in it.starmap(dynamics, paramsIter):
#     i

# end = timer()
# print(end - start)
```

Comment: Do you have any numbers on occupancy of each core? BTW: 705/85=8.2 which = num cores.

Comment: Using top/htop I can see the serial version runs one process which ends up using 100% of 4 cores while the multiprocessing runs eight processes that end up taking 100% of all 8 cores. If I run the function for 12 values instead of 6, the serial version takes 963 seconds vs. 1250 seconds using multiprocessing.